# Vim - difference between typed keys and keys from mapping?

Tags: vim

In Vim's documentation of `feedkeys()`, the description of mode `t` reads:

```
    't' Handle keys as if typed; otherwise they are handled as
        if coming from a mapping.  This matters for undo,
        opening folds, etc.
```

What is this difference?  In what ways do keys coming from mappings behave differently and why does this difference matter for undo, opening folds, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping sequence is atomized for undo.

If you change the text with many command, then undo will undo it back changes by changes.

If you map same sequence of command to mapping, and try undo it, it will bring back changes in state before running mapping.

For example: you have text '12345' with cursor on 2. You 3 time hit 'x'. You need 3 time hit 'u' to bring the text back.

If you make mapping:

```
:map q xxx
```

After you press q, you can bring back change with only one pressing 'u'.

Also from `:h map-undo`:

> If you include an undo command inside a mapped sequence, this will bring the text back in the state before executing the macro. This is compatible with
>   the original Vi

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks!  Is there similar behavior for functions?  I noticed that if I have `new` in the middle of my function and then have some commands afterward, the new window only appears with the results of those commands rather than first appearing empty and then seeing it populated, as though it were all a single atomic operation.

Comment: Yes. Also for you will be interesting `:help undo-blocks`. And from `:help undo` this `When manual folding is being used, the folds are not saved and restored. Only changes completely within a fold will keep the fold as it was, because the first and last line of the fold don't change`

Comment: Yes I had some difficulty with this when I tried using manual folds on files under version control -- switching branches broke the folds.